# C# Voice bot does not responding to my instructions

Tags: c#, winforms, voice-recognition, voice

I wanted to try sound recognition in C#,but the program is not responding.I had a problem with the language before(my language is Czech),but I solved it by setting Culture.But no output comes out of the program.It does not respond to my instructions
I also tested the microphone,but it is fine.
Do you know what to do?

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace Test_Bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine engine =
    new SpeechRecognitionEngine(
      new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            engine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            btnDisable.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "Say hello", "Print my name" });
            GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            gBuilder.Append(commands);
            Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

            engine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
            engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            engine.SpeechRecognized += engine_SpeechRecognized;
        }

        void engine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {

            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "Say hello":
                    MessageBox.Show("Hi Peter");
                    break;

                case "Print my name":
                    richTextBox1.Text += "\nPeter";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            engine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            btnDisable.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @MindSwipe so I should just do `var task = engine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar); ` ?

Comment: In most of the examples of how to create voice recognition program they were using those methods

Comment: Disregard my previous comments, turns out the [`SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammarAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.loadgrammarasync?view=netframework-4.8) isn't named in the same convention as every other async method in .NET is, they're not typical async methods as well. Thanks Jimi for pointing that out

Comment: @MindSwipe So It is not the problem of my project?

Comment: Nope, I just saw a method ending in `Async` and no await and assumed that's the problem as it's a very common mistake. You could try subscribing to the [`LoadGrammarCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.loadgrammarcompleted?view=netframework-4.8) event to see if your grammar gets successfully loaded (there's an example in the linked documentation to check that)

Comment: You're missing `engine.RequestRecognizerUpdate();` before you set the new Grammar; if it's a new (and only Grammar) it shouldn't matter. But, how did you set the Language to English, since yours is Czech?

Comment: @I did it in Windows and  changed `SpeechRecognitionEngine receng =  new SpeechRecognitionEngine(  new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")); `

Comment: Do you have that System Language? If you open the Speech Properties, can you select an `en-GB` voice? Or do you have `en-US` voices? [Trivial] Have you tested whether the Microphone is working correctly?

Comment: @Jimi So I should set `engine.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); `  before `Grammar grammar... = new Grammar(gBuilder);`?

Comment: You usually call that method when you change / update the Grammar and reset a speech recognition in progress to use the new choices. It's called in a general Speech Recognition Engine initialization procedure. -- You should verify that your System can handle the Language you've set.

Comment: @Jimi I've tested if my micro works and cheked Languange system of course

Comment: So, you say that a breakpoint set in `engine_SpeechRecognized` is never hit? Have you tested whether the System Recognition applet is actually working, not just Text to Speech? Try to explicitly set the `Culture` to the `GrammarBuilder` -- Why do you have `receng` and `engine` there?

Comment: @Jimi Yeah,I went through debbugger,but the value is null and never touches any value .How to test the System Recognition applet?Receng was just mistake,I edited it

Comment: To make it clear, a breakpoint set in `engine_SpeechRecognized` does get hit or not? What is *value is null*? If the handler is reached, is it `e.Result.Text`? In this case, have you checked the  `e.Result.Confidence`? -- If you posted redacted code, try to post your real code, since the previous `receng` and `engine` mishap suggests you're posting modified code. Unless you're using your local language to name those objects and you simply *translated* them to English.

Comment: @Jimi   `engine_SpeechRecognized` does not get hit at all

Comment: @Jimi I did some research on the internet.Is it possible,that System.Speech does not support my OS?(Windows 11).It seems to me as stupid thing,but I'm new in voice recognition,so I'm not a sure

Comment: I don't know, I've never tested it in this System. You may want to read this: [Speech, voice, and conversation in Windows 11 and Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/speech) and this: [Speech recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/speech-recognition), setup an UWP app and test it with `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` following the example there. Or test the [System.Speech](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Speech/) integration for .Net 6. The standard `System.Speech` is for .Net Framework only.

Comment: @Jimi Okay,I will try.I found on the internet Google Assistant API on Google Cloud.Is it for free?